# How do I initialize a tree node to debug?

Tags: c#, binary-tree

Silly question but new to binary trees

I have this example I want to debug from leetcode. To debug I need to send valid values as q and p. But I don't seem to be able to initialize my nodes the way as requested to test the answers and learn.

```
public class TreeNode
    {
      public int val;
      public TreeNode left;
      public TreeNode right;
    public TreeNode(int val = 0, TreeNode left = null, TreeNode right = null)
        {
            this.val = val;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
         }
    }
    public bool IsSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q)
    {
        if (p == null && q == null) return true;
        if (p == null || q == null) return false;

        if (p.val == q.val)
        {
            return IsSameTree(p.left, q.left) && IsSameTree(p.right, q.right);
        }

        return false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program pr = new Program();
```

> my problem is here, I need to send an exmaple of p and q as
> p = [1,2,3], q = [1,2,3] and output true;
> or
> Input: p = [1,2], q = [1,null,2]
> Output: false

Input: p = [1,2,1], q = [1,1,2]
Output: false

**Question**: How do I Initialize p and q with the previous examples?
So the method IsSameTree() gets them;

[image]

```
 TreeNode p = new TreeNode();
        p.val = 1;
        p.left = new TreeNode();
        p.left.val = 2;
        p.right = new TreeNode();
        p.right.val = 1;

        TreeNode q = new TreeNode();
        q.val = 1;
        q.left = new TreeNode();
        q.left.val = 1;
        q.right = new TreeNode();
        q.right.val = 2;
        bool isIdentical = pr.IsSameTree(p,q);
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? What this code returns?

Comment: My exact problem is that I need to send p and q with different variants to be able to debug this code. 

I need to be able to Input: p = [1,2], q = [1,null,2]
Output: false

or Input: p = [1,2], q = [1,null,2]
Output: false

The example provided returns true, but I can't seem so be able to give live to p and q in a proper way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer

Representation of:
Input: p = [1,2], q = [1,null,2]
Output: false

```
TreeNode p = new TreeNode(1, left: new TreeNode(val:2));
   TreeNode q = new TreeNode(val:1, left:null, right: new TreeNode(2));
   bool isIdentical = pr.IsSameTree(p,q);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what your problem is. Were you expecting p and q to be equal? Then you should initialize them the same way. Also you're checking p agains p, which will return on the basic equality.

Try this:

```cs
TreeNode p = new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(3));
TreeNode q = new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(3));
bool isIdentical = pr.IsSameTree(p,q);
```

Comment: I should be able to enter the following
Input: p = [1,2], q = [1,null,2]
Output: false
Input: p = [1,2], q = [1,null,2]
Output: false

the code works on leetcode but can't seem to debug it since the initialization of p and q doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: you were very close, just needed to specify left and right in the constructor